# Visualizing categorical data in scatter plot with Orange (version > 3.18)

Tags: orange, plotting

Why in Orange versions after 3.18 is not possible to visualize categorical data in Scatter Plot widget?

Comment: Orange official doc states otherwise, showcasing support for both, continuous as well as discrete-valued attributes. Have you cross-checked datatype of your features?
If sure at your end, try reaching out their contributors on GitHub. They've pretty similar bugs reported lately. Check https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/4369

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm shure about my question. Consequently I have installed every version from 3.15 to 3.24 and 3.18 is the last version which supports the visualization of categorical data in Scatter Plot, although the statements in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you can change the data type in the file widget, from Categorical to Continuous. Then you can use scatter plot.